# A Fast Series to Pi

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So after my last question on why $$\tan\left(3\right)+{\pi} \approx 3$$ I figured that I could do this:
$$
{\pi} = {3} - {\tan 3} - \tan({3} - {\tan 3})-\tan({3} - {\tan 3} - \tan({3} - {\tan 3}))...
$$
because $ 3 - \tan 3 \approx \pi$ and each term is $-\tan x$ where $x$ is very close to $0$ or $\pi$.

I tried to convert this to a power series so that I could get a power series for $\pi$, but I got stuck on the first step:
$$ 
\tan x = \sum_{i=0}^\inf a_ix^i
$$
I don't know the $a_i$, but I can compute them to as many terms as I want. I tried to simplify:
$$
\pi = {3} - {\sum_{i = 0}^\inf}a_iy^i - {\sum_{j = 0}^\inf}a_j(3-{\sum_{i = 0}^\inf}a_iy^i)^j...
$$
(Where $y = 3 - \tan 3$)
As I can compute the $a_{(i/j/...)}$, I know the first two terms.

How do I simplify this to 
$$ 
\sum_{i=0}^\inf b_i3^i?
$$

Comment: Do lots of differentiation or search for the Taylor series for tan.  It won't converge for 3 though: that's outside its radius of convergence.  Here's one that I found for you: scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/taylor11.pdf.

Comment: It won't? I'll change it to expand near 3.

Comment: Yes, the radius of convergence is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.  Draw a graph of tan and it should be obvious that there is a problem there.  Some functions have an infinite radius of convergence e.g. $\exp$, $\sin$, and $\cos$.  Some have 0.